# What about $W^*$ when $W = \{(x_1, ..., x_n)| x_1+...+x_n=0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I considered the basis $$\{e_1-e_2, ... , e_1-e_n\}$$ for $W$, and so found the dual basis $\{f_1, ..., f_n\}$, where $$f_i =-x_i+c \sum_{k=1}^n x_k .$$

However, it is asked to show that $W^*$ can be naturally identified with the linear functionals $$f(x_1, ..., x_n) = c_1x_1+...+c_nx_n$$ with $c_1+...+c_n=0$.

Can someone give me some hint on how to show this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V=\mathbb{R}^n$ Then $V^\ast =\{ f_x|x\in V\},\ f_x(y)=(x,y)$.

Hence $W^\ast =\{f_x| x\in W\}$. Hence $ f_x(y)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$

[Another] $f(x)=\sum_i\ c_ix_i$ is linear map. Hence $f\in W^\ast$.

If $$g(x)=\sum_i\
 c_ix_i -\sum_i\ \frac{ (\sum_i\ c_i) }{n} x_i,$$
 then $f=g$. That
 is, $W^\ast \subset \{ f|f(x)=\sum_i\ c_ix_i,\ \sum_i\ c_i=0\}$. By
 considering a dimension, they are equal.

Comment: I got your hint. In fact, you are using the result that says every linear functional can be written by using inner product. However, the question is given in Chapter 3 of Hoffman's Linear Algebra. Do you have some other idea without using the inner product spaces?

Comment: I see. I add more explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I got it!